# How to create a VPN config file for sharing with others?

Tags: settings, vpn

I've a VPN server and want to let others connect to it.

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I'd like to create a VPN config file with all the necessary credentials so that my friends can simply open it and have a VPN profile set up.

Is it possible to make a config file?

Comment: Which VPN (protocol) server you have set up?

Comment: @IrfanLatif L2TP

Comment: I have never come across a VPN configuration file other than OpenVPN. They have a kinda standardized `.ovpn` format. I have an OpenVPN server and I create configurations using a shell script. My friends have just to import the file in client app, no manual entry at all. L2TP has very minimal configuration and clients usually (AFAIK) don't support importing saved configuration. Check with your client apps (I suppose on Android) if they have some option to import configuration. Then a standard configuration file can be created.